# How to show database stored multiple dates in calendar control with different color

Tags: c#, asp.net

using Asp.net, c# and MS Sql Database created a **Room Booking APP**
I need the following Code in C#

I have database (rmBooking_tbl) with variable Checkindt and checkoutdt (NVARCHAR(50)) and stored room booking dates

1. Now I want to show these booked date ranges(Check in date to check out date) in calendar1 by highlighting with some different color and also should be disabled these dates for further selecting
2. disable all previous dates from current date

Please help me for creating code

Comment: may i know which date control you are using ?

Comment: calendar control in standard  tool tab in visual studio 2019